# Handling Form errors in the controller ( Ajax call )

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'd like to have **the field name** in addition to the error message.

I performed the following set of instructions to put all errors into an array :

```
$errors= array();

foreach ($newRdvForm->getErrors(true) as $key => $error) {
     $errors[$key] = $error->getMessage();
}
```

So what can i to have the field name of each input ?

If there are other method, feel free to publish it

Comment: Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: Symfony 2.7 ..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FormInterface::getErrors()](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_getErrors) method returns a [FormErrorIterator instance](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Form/FormErrorIterator.html). The underlying [FormError](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Form/FormError.html) objects provide a [getOrigin()](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Form/FormError.html#method_getOrigin) method which returns the [FormInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html) the error relates to.